# How to move from Java to JavaScript developer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have strong Java background and I would like to extend my knowledge to JavaScript based frameworks. After few days of learning AngularJS I see, that lot of code needs to have predefined structure (e.g. config() function from the ngRoute), which writing by hand may introduce errors in the code.
My questions are:

1. Is there some IDE which supports generating such a code templates?
2. How to work with the code - in Java when I wanted to know, the basics of some class I hit CTRL + space (eclipse) and I knew, what's going on. Is there a similar functionality in any IDE?
3. Should good JavaScript developer remember exact code snippets like e.g.

```js
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url:'/',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl : 'views/header.html'
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl : 'views/main.html',
                controller  : 'MainCtrl'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl : 'views/footer.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

or is it allowed to generate them or copy-paste from sites like SO.

Comment: This is not a place to start a discussion, this is a place to ask your programming code doubts, your question doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

your first two questions answer is **WEBSTORM** IDE , this is very good javascript IDE (you can use Ctr + space to get autocomplete feature like eclipse).

Good javascript developer never remember code snippets , you  should learn basics of javascript like objects , properties,functions etc.

once you learn these things , you will  understand the code snippet ,but no need to remember snippet.

java and javascript both object oriented language except inheritance , java support inheritance while javascript not.

you can also learn javascript from mozila developer , here is the link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there some IDE which supports generating such a code templates?

   > Most of the Angular Developers either use Webstorm, Sublime or Atom. But most would agree that Webstorm is ahead of the pack by a fair bit. Again, its a personal choice. Webstorm supports intellisense and generates pre defined templates.
2. How to work with the code - in Java when I wanted to know, the basics of some class I hit CTRL + space (eclipse) and I knew, what's going on. Is there a similar functionality in any IDE?

   > Webstorm, Sublime or Atom do support intellisense
3. Should good JavaScript developer remember exact code snippets like e.g.

   > Its not the end of the world if you don't remember the exact syntax. You can always look up the reference materials. Angular can get a little overwhelming when you see it first. But trust me, once you start coding, most of the syntax would make sense and like Ernest Nowacki mentioned, you would be able to code like the back of your hand.

Answer (score 0):

In JetBrains WebStorm there is a feature called Live Templates where you could define your own abbreviations for common tasks. For example writing "ngcmp" can result in auto generating component wrapper. You can feel free to add your own like routing.

WebStorm ships with few angular live templates included.

Nowadays there's also a trend with using command line tools to autogenerate angular files with proper structure to avoid copy + paste boilerplate. You can go ahead and try yeoman generators or angular CLI for angular 2.

In general while you start I would stick around with templates. It's pretty easy to get familiar with most commonly used syntax and I believe most of angular 1.x developers can write proper structure from top of the head.